# Resize all ImageViews in a layout

Tags: android

I have four `ImageViews` in a layout. I set the maximum width for each one of them by `setMaxWidth` function. The problem is that they keep a small distance between them and I don't want that. If I don't stipulate the maximum width, these gaps disappear, but the `ImageViews` sizes are inappropriate (bigger than it should be).

The main code is:

```
    musicSubmenuButton = new ImageView(context);
    musicSubmenuButton.setId(id++);
    musicSubmenuButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_musicas_on);  
    musicSubmenuButton.setMaxWidth(buttonSize);
    musicSubmenuButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    photosSubmenuButton = new ImageView(context);
    photosSubmenuButton.setId(id++);
    photosSubmenuButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_fotos_off);
    photosSubmenuButton.setMaxWidth(buttonSize);
    photosSubmenuButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    agendaSubmenuButton = new ImageView(context);
    agendaSubmenuButton.setId(id++);
    agendaSubmenuButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_agenda_off); 
    agendaSubmenuButton.setMaxWidth(buttonSize);
    agendaSubmenuButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    infoSubmenuButton = new ImageView(context);
    infoSubmenuButton.setId(id++);
    infoSubmenuButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_info_off);
    infoSubmenuButton.setMaxWidth(buttonSize);
    infoSubmenuButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

The size I wanted, but without the gaps (obtained using the above code): [image]

The ImageViews without the gaps, but in the original resolution (obtained using the above code, but commenting the `setAdjustViewBounds` calls): [image]

Does anybody know why these gaps appear and/or a workaround to get rid of these gaps and keep my desired size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting max width, set layout_width on them to fill_parent.  Then they will space out evenly.

Comment: Thanks Zack! It worked! I added the code in your post to make the solution more clear :D. Do you know why the gaps were appearing in the way I was doing?